# SUM specific column using group by and how to avoid least joining table values from that?

Tags: mysql

i have query select of 3 tables using left joins by that i want sum of second table column value but by adding third table join we get some extra column on summing second table column value i need to avoid this

here explanation,
indents(table 1)

```
indent_no   |   indent_name  |  request_qty
1131              AAA            834
```

purchase_order(table 2)

```
pur_id  |  pur_qty  |  indent_no
121         34        1131
122        100        1131
123         10        1131
```

grn (table 3)

```
grn_no |  grn_val   | pur_id
1         34           121
2         23           121
3         21           122
```

my query to get sum(purchase_order.pur_qty) it should be 144 right
but i am getting 178 because the grn table contains 2 rows for pur_id(121)
**pls note i can only allowed to use group by clause for indents.indent_no
only**

i tried to get 144 but getting 178 ... see you can get actual result if you use group by purchase_order.pur_id and with the select of sum(purchase_order.pur_qty)/count(grn.pur_id) but i cant use group by column other than indents.indent_no

```
select sum(purchase_order.pur_qty) from indents
left join purchase_order on purchase_order.indent_no = indents.indent_no
left join grn on grn.pur_id = purchase_order.pur_id
group by indents.indent_no
```

i want the result

```
indent_no sum(purchase_order.pur_qty)  SUM(grn_val)
1131            144                      78
```

Comment: `SELECT indent_no, SUM(pur_qty) x FROM purchase_order GROUP BY indent_no;`

Comment: Yep, just add `indent_no,` to the `SELECT` part like @Strawberry said.

Comment: What's the purpose of joining with the `grn` table, since you're not using it?

Comment: im using grn table value

Comment: But in your example you're just summing everything up for `grn_val`, not grouping by `indent_no`

Comment: yes but this is the scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this query,  

 select indents.indent_no,sum(DISTINCT(purchase_order.pur_qty)),sum(grn.grn_val) from indents
    left join purchase_order on purchase_order.indent_no = indents.indent_no
    left join grn on grn.pur_id = purchase_order.pur_id
    group by indents.indent_no
```

Comment: How and why is this the best answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - you don't need to join with grn table as you only want to sum of purchage qty

```
select indents.indent_no,sum(purchase_order.pur_qty) from indents
left join purchase_order on purchase_order.indent_no = indents.indent_no
group by indents.indent_no
```

In case you need to join with grn table then you can do this using subquery of grn table -

You can see that grn table has multiple value of one purchase id and that's reason of duplication and you get wrong result from your current query

```
select indents.indent_no,sum(purchase_order.pur_qty) from indents
    left join purchase_order on purchase_order.indent_no = indents.indent_no
    left join (select pur_id, sum(grn_va) as gval from grn group by pur_id) as grn
    on grn.pur_id = purchase_order.pur_id
    group by indents.indent_no
```

Comment: i should use grn table thats why i am facing this issue

Comment: @CharlesMichel, ok then you can go with 2nd solution